# react native : situation where I want to reach a certain page with a shortcut after I shut down the app and turned it on again?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

what is the way to resolve situation where I want to reach a certain page with a shortcut after I shut down the app and turned it on again ?

Comment: You can use [deep linking](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking). While entering a page, save the link url somewhere. While launching the app, check the saved url and restore the page.

Comment: page i mean not http page.. i mean my app page. i try to shortcut to some page of my app after i shout down the app and back to it again . i like if u can help with this issue .

Comment: I meant the app page, if you're using react nativigation, deep linking is a standard way to do it. You should check their [documents](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/)